# Best way to identify what's crashing Print Spooler?

Tags: windows, print-server

I have a client with a centralized print server (Windows Server 2019) that manages about 65 printers with ~200 users (max). The Windows Print Spooler crashes 5+ times a day, and it's always due to faulting module "wsnmp.dll". From what I've been able to find online so far, I suspect that one or more of the client's Konika-Minolta printers is causing the crashes, but I'd like to be able to know for certain before I start suggesting impactful changes such as disabling SNMP (the solution I found online).

I ran across Microsoft's Application Verifier but am unsure whether this will provide the information I'm looking for. I also want to minimize disruption to the client. Print Spooler is currently set to always restart upon a crash, and it does so every time with no noticeable impact to print services. If I have Application Verifier monitor the Print Spooler and related processes, will Application Verifier stop Print Spooler from rebooting when it crashes? The crashing doesn't occur often enough for me to watch for a crash and manually restart the Print Spooler.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It’s always a bad print driver that eill crash the spooler. Update the bugged one !

Check your eventlog for the dll and find the path of it to list its property. You will find the brand and possibly which one is causing the bug.

When you will know the one that bug, start by validating that your print driver are in Isolated Mode. Such mode isolate the driver, thus when it fail only the print queue related to that driver fail and it recover.

You have a printer stress tool that exist from citrix that is used on Windows Server, but I simply recommand at first to upgrade those drivers at first and if it still crash try to use their universal’s driver.

Comment: The universal driver doesn't help the situation. Can you tell me how to find the crashing dll? All I can find from Event Viewer is the crashing module, which is Windows' SNMP dll.

Comment: @DB_2022 As you suspect the Konika I thougth you had event related. Disable SNMP in the TCP/IP printqueue for them would be my next move then. btw It's not such a problematic move to do, I can state I often do it, as in example my biggest print server have like 200 printers on it but all multisites, it was creating unwanted traffic on all the vpn tunnel.